# How to configure feature flags in Rabbitmq when using docker image?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am trying to create a docker container with a rabbitMQ image, and then join that instance to an existing cluster.

However I get the error incompatible_feature_flags

It looks like the created image automatically enables some feature flags that are not enabled and cannot be enabled in the existing cluster.

I am running the container using the following code:

```
docker run -d --hostname xxx.yyy.com.co --name rabbit -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 -p 4369:4369 --add-host='rabbit1:xxx.xxx.xx.xxx' --network=host -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=admin -e RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE='xxxxxxxx' -e ERL_EPMD_PORT=4369 rabbitmq:latest
```

I think that I can enable/disable feature flags as parameters when starting the container, but I have not been able to find anything in the documentation.

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be caused by the different version between the tow RabbitMQ applications.

eg: one is 3.7.x, but the another is 3.8.x .